# How to not set the default date in CalendarView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, calendarview

So I have a calendarView in android but it always defaults to the current date. I wanted it to just show the current month with no date selected by default. I tried searching online but I did not get any answers. How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

I did a little research, but I couldn't find the exact solution you wanted.
You can use Material CalendarView. I hope this helps you..

https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RN4Zmxlah_I

Answer (score -1):

I think a default value is a right way , why don't u want a default value ? if u show this calendar view ,there must be a ok or cancel button , what will u do if user doesn't do anything and only click ok button ?
so I think u'd better set a default value .